# Metacharacter \B matches (OCP exam)

Tags: java, regex, ocpjp

I am studying for the Java OCP certificate. I am taking mock exams to prepare.

Example program:

```
public class Quetico {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0]);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(args[1]);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.start() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

the authors of the OCA/OCP Jave SE 7 Study Guide maintain that the execution:

```
java Quetico "\B" "^23 *$76 bc"
```

will produce the output

```
0 2 4 8
```

However, when I run the code from Eclipse or [test it on an outside source](https://regex101.com/r/eJ6zF6/1), I get

```
0 2 4 5 7 10
```

Am I missing something here, or is it a mistake by the authors of the study guide?

I am adding the actual question from the book below for reference.

#### Question from the Book

[image: OCP Java 7 Self Test Question 8.3]

#### Answer

[image]

Comment: ya, 2 one is the correct one. Does `"\B"` would be passed as `\\B` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Command-line input does not have to be escaped, so `"\B"` is equal to a Java String `"\\B"` passed in directly in the code.

Comment: `mistake by the authors of the study guide` If you run the code and get the same result, it must be considered the claim is in error. Regex engine primitives don't change, in fact `\B` means not-word boundary on probably every engine. So, is it possible the claim is in error ? I'd say so..

Comment: @sln Thanks. These kind of exams have a lot of trick questions, so you start to doubt everything you see. My only hope is they have thoroughly debugged the actual exam questions.

Comment: I have an exam for your exam makers. They should send all their questions to me to check their work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book is correct (when executing over a Unix machine with the usual shells). It is a combination of shell behaviour and java (in my opinion, off-topic to a course of Java). Remember "$" in shell means replacement. So, if you call the program as:

```
java Quetico "\B" "^23 *$76 bc"
```

the string that is matched over regex is (you can add a println for args[1] to verify it):

```
^23 *6 bc
```

with the result given by the book "0 2 4 8".

You can compare the result with the one of:

```
java Quetico "\B" '^23 *$76 bc'
```

that disables shell substitution.

Comment: You are completely right! Why would they put something like that in the exam? It's trick questions like these that I hate, because you're not really testing someone's knowledge of Java. Thanks for figuring this one out!

Comment: @Neftas: my hypothesis is authors have included the "$" in the question, executed the program and copied the answer to the book, without see the "special" meaning of this symbol. Well, at least, they have tested the examples, a lot of books doesn't ;-)

Comment: Yes, and I was testing the code using eclim (which uses a headless Eclipse instance), so I bypassed the shell while passing arguments to the program... It all figures, mystery solved :)